# If $x^2$ and $x^3$ are rational, does it imply that $x$ is rational?

Tags: proof-verification, logic, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

It is given that $x^2$ is rational and $x^3$ is rational.

Is $x$ rational for all cases satisfying these conditions or is there are case where $x$ won't be rational?
If so, then what other condition(s) are required?

Comment: Check $x = \frac{x^3}{x^2}$ if $x^2 \neq 0$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, indeed it implies that $x$ is rational. Because $x^2$ and $x^3$ are rational, $\frac{x^3}{x^2}$ is also a rational number if $x≠0$. ($\Bbb Q \setminus \{0\}$ is a group under ordinary multiplication). Hence $x$ is a rational number.

Comment: $\Bbb Q \setminus \{0\} $ is not a field.

Comment: Ok. Let me correct myself, it is a group under ordinary multiplication.